# mocking extended classes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-mock

I am trying to mock a library in Python 2.7 and am running into issues. What I currently have worked but I would like to extend it to be able to differentiate between different subprocess calls. I'd like to do this by reading the second element in my args array, passed into `MockedPopen`. My issues are that I do not have access to this value when I create the class `stdout` inside `MockedPopen`. My method to this point has been to mock out everything up to `whmapicall.stdout.read()` but I can't seem to pass self into this new class because the value is not yet created.

```
class MockedPopen:
    PIPE = None
    def __init__(self, args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.returncode = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, value, traceback):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def Popen(self, cmd , **kwargs):
        return self

    class stdout():
        stdout = '''---
data:
  acct:
    -
      bwusage:
        -
          deleted: 0
          domain: hd.tld
          usage: 771853
      deleted: 0
      limit: '88048926720'
      maindomain: hd.tld
      owner: root
      reseller: 0
      totalbytes: 771853
      user: hd
  month: 9
  reseller: root
  totalused: 232307616
  year: 2019
metadata:
  command: showbw
  reason: OK
  result: 1
  version: 1'''

        @classmethod
        def read(self):
            return self.stdout
```

**My test Class**

```
 class TestInit:
     @mock.patch('cpquotafix.subprocess', MockedPopen)
     def testUsername(self):
         user = cpquotafix.User("eddy","cthulhu","hd.tld","root",  None ,"10000")
         assert user.username == "eddy"
```

**The code I want to patch out**

```
def setBandwidthLimit(self):
    whmapicall   = subprocess.Popen(["whmapi1" , "showbw", 'searchtype=user', 'search=^%s$' % self.username], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    whmapireturn = whmapicall.stdout.read().split("\n")
```

```
def setPackageQuota(self):
    whmapicall   = subprocess.Popen(["whmapi1" , "getpkginfo", "pkg=%s" % self.plan], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    whmapireturn = whmapicall.stdout.read().split("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `stdout` to be a class. You can make `stdout` a property instead and make it return a `Mock` object with `read` attribute defined as a `Mock` object that, when called, returns the desired string based on the arguments that were passed to the `MockedPopen`:

```
class MockedPopen:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args

    @property
    def stdout(self):
        return mock.Mock(read=mock.Mock(return_value='''blah blah
metadata:
  command: {}
blah blah'''.format(self.args[1])))
```

Comment: My issues are that I want to change the return value based on what is passed into my mock_popen

`if self.args[1] == 'showbw':` and `if self.args[1] == 'getpkginfo'` or the first list that is passed into the subprocess.Popen. Ideal I want to return a different data structure based on what kind of API call is made.